# How can I read international characters from console

Tags: java, console

How can I read international characters from console in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`java.io.Console`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class, just like any other character. The question is whether the console itself supports those "international characters", but that has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: what does that have to do with?

Comment: @mkoryak: `java.io.Console` provides *"Methods to access the character-based console device, if any, associated with the current Java virtual machine..."* So then you're dealing with characters, rather than the bytes you get from `System.in`. At that point, the characters are characters, and hopefully handled properly by the console in question.

Comment: @mkoryak: it depends on the console itself, i.e. the program that displays the command line. It may also depend on OS settings. Basically, if you can type something like "echo MyDesiredCharacters > out.txt" and have the characters show up correctly in the txt file, it should work file with Java as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't for some reason use `java.io.Console` as [suggested by Michael Borgwardt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507789/how-can-i-read-international-characters-from-console/2507807#2507807), you can use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) around `System.in`, since `System.in` is an `InputStream`. You tell the `InputStreamReader` what character set you're expecting to receive as part of construction, either via a [`Charset`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) or a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't resolve the problem since I'm a beginner. I'd like to use UTF-8 charset.
If I type the "aákú" (or any text with non english characters) the program will hangs up!

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type any text:");
    String text = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(text);
```

The InputSream class make some result like System.in...

Comment: The solution: set the encode properties from UTF-8 to ANSI-1250 on project properties...